# excel: most used numbers from massive

Tags: excel

[image: Example]

How to get a formula, which will show 6 most used numbers from C2:H17 with persantage?

```
    L#01    L#02    L#03    L#04    L#05    L#06
29.12.2015  2   25  27  11  29  4
29.12.2015  2   37  12  11  69  3
30.12.2015  1   14  22  19  25  28
31.12.2015  31  37  44  26  12  39
01.01.2016  32  1   22  41  26  14
02.01.2016  15  55  26  24  33  26
03.01.2016  11  13  12  37  48  35
04.01.2016  42  14  8   35  2   35
05.01.2016  16  64  16  42  24  2
06.01.2016  42  33  36  22  4   35
07.01.2016  17  44  17  3   24  35
08.01.2016  46  28  4   36  25  37
09.01.2016  3   23  46  44  4   7
10.01.2016  22  22  24  47  26  37
11.01.2016  46  35  47  48  27  77
```

Comment: Why are you going to make those that want to help type their own array to test?  You should put the values themselves in the post so we can copy and paste, not a picture.

Comment: Coz i can't attach excel file...

Comment: Post the data directly as text into the Original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a standard [MODE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MODE-function-E45192CE-9122-4980-82ED-4BDC34973120) or the newer [MODE.SNGL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MODE-SNGL-function-f1267c16-66c6-4386-959f-8fba5f8bb7f8) to retrieve the first MODE (most frequent) number. Optionally add a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) to indicate the number of occurances.

In J4 as a standard formula,

```
=MODE.SNGL($C$3:$H$17)
```

For the second through sixth MODE numbers, create an array formula that looks at previous returns and discards then from consideration.

In J5 as an array¹ formula.

```
=MODE.SNGL(IF(NOT(COUNTIF(J$4:J4, $C$3:$H$17)), $C$3:$H$17))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: mode_ordinals]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: You could use `=MODE.SNGL(IF(COUNTIF($J$2:$J2,$C$3:$H$17)=0,$C$3:$H$17))` as an array in all. Nevermind I should have known you would see it.

Comment: It did worked with (=MODE.SNGL($C$3:$H$17)) J4... but once i try to enter (=MODE.SNGL(IF(NOT(COUNTIF(J$4:J4, $C$3:$H$17)), $C$3:$H$17))) to J5.. with CTRL+SHFT+ENTR i've got error msg: "When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula...." did a missed something?

Comment: I hope you are not putting the outside braces / brackets in yourself. Go back and read the footnote I included. Perhaps you should have a look at the [sample workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/MODE_first_second_third_place.xlsb).

Comment: yeah,,, works now... problem was in (,) and (;) in formula. Cheers! Could you tell how you highlighed numbers?

Comment: Yes, that is one of the problems that are avoided when any sort of formula (working or not) is provided but sadly, that was not the case here. The number highlighting was done with a series of six conditional formatting rules. See [the sample workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/MODE_first_second_third_place.xlsb).

Comment: that might be noob question, but i an't find how you did highlight :(

Comment: Select any cell in the C3:H17 range and go to Home, Styles, Conditional Formatting, Manage rules.